Trouble with proof that $L^p(\mathbb R ^n)$ is separable
I'm having trouble understanding the following proof from Linear Functional Analysis - An Application-Oriented Introduction (4.18, Proof for (4)):
Let $\epsilon>0, 0<p<\infty$ and $f\in L^p(\mathbb R ^n)$. Let further
$$
Q_\epsilon(z) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n ; z_i \leq x_i \leq z_i + \epsilon \ \text{for} \ i = 1, \ldots, n \} \ \text{for} \ z \in \epsilon \mathbb{Z}^n
$$
We define the piecewise constant interpolation $f_\epsilon$ as:
$$
f_\epsilon(x) := \sum_{z \in \epsilon \mathbb{Z}^n} \chi_{Q_\epsilon(z)}(x) \alpha_{\epsilon, z}, \ \ \alpha_{\epsilon, z} := \frac{1}{\epsilon^n} \int_{Q_\epsilon(z)} f(y) \, dy
$$
This interpolant approximates $f$, since:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f_\epsilon(x) - f(x)|^p \, dx & = \sum_z \int_{Q_\epsilon(z)} |\alpha_{\epsilon, z} - f(x)|^p \, dx\\
& = \sum_z \int_{Q_\epsilon(z)} \left| \frac{1}{\epsilon^n} \int_{Q_\epsilon(z)} (f(y) - f(x)) \, dy \right|^p \, dx \label{1}\tag{1}\\
& = \sum_z \frac{1}{\epsilon^n} \int_{Q_\epsilon(z)} \int_{Q_\epsilon(z)} |f(y) - f(x)|^p \, dy \, dx\label{2}\tag{2}\\
& \leq \sup_{h : |h| \leq \epsilon} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(y + h) - f(y)|^p \, dy = \sup_{h : |h| \leq \epsilon} \| f(\cdot + h) - f \|_{L^p}^p.\label{3}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

I'm honestly totally lost: In \eqref{1} for example, I don't see how we can factor out $\frac{1}{\epsilon^n}$ like that. I tried doing it step by step, but I get:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{z}\int_{Q_\epsilon(z)}\left|\alpha_{\epsilon,z}-f(x)\right|^p\, dx
& =\sum_{z}\int_{Q_\epsilon(z)}\Bigg|\bigg(\frac{1}{\epsilon^n}\underbrace{\int_{Q_\epsilon(z)} f(y)\, d y}_{=:u}\bigg)-f(x)\Bigg|^p\, dx
\\
& =\sum_{z}\int_{Q_\epsilon(z)}\left|\frac{1}{\epsilon^n}\left(u-\epsilon^nf(x)\right)\right|^p\, dx
\\
& =\frac{1}{\epsilon^n}\sum_{z}\int_{Q_\epsilon(z)}\left|u-\epsilon^nf(x)\right|^p\, dx
\\
& =\frac{1}{\epsilon^n}\sum_{z}\int_{Q_\epsilon(z)}\left|\int_{Q_\epsilon(z)}{f(y)-\epsilon^nf(x)}\, d y\right|^p\, dx
\end{align}
$$
But for $\epsilon\neq 1$ this seems distinct from \eqref{2}.
For \eqref{2} I do not understand why we have an equality, and why it holds for all $p$. I could get an inequality $\le$ since for any function $g$ we have $\left|\int_{\Omega} gd\mu\right|\le\int_{\Omega}\left|g\right|d\mu$ and we maybe can fit Jensen's inequality, but that'd only give an inequality?

What does this have to do with the separability of $L_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$? If separability is what you are interested in, then notice that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is countably generated (the collection $\mathcal{C}$ of boxes with rational center and rational radii generate it).

@Mittens If we let $\epsilon\to 0 $ for the last formula, we get $|f-f_e|_p\to 0$. The set of these interpolating functions therefore is countably by construction and dense in $L_p(\mathbb R^n)$, and therefore $L_p(\mathbb R^n)$ is separable.

Your argument shows that integrable simple functions are dense in $L_p$ (but for separability you want a countable collection of simple functions). Also the dimensions in (1) and (3) do not match one if $f$ was measure in meters for exmple (1) has meters^p and (3) has meters. It seems you need a power in (3).

@Mittens You're right, I missed a power of $p$ when typing it off. I've corrected it now

In \eqref{1} the catch is that $\varepsilon^n$ is indeed the volume of $Q_{\varepsilon}(z)$, since it is an $n$-block with edge length $\varepsilon$. With that we get:
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_z \int_{Q_{\varepsilon}(z)} |\alpha(x) - f(x)|^p dx 
&= \sum_z \int_{Q_{\varepsilon}(z)} \left|\frac{1}{\varepsilon^n}\int_{Q_{\varepsilon}(z)}f(y)dy - f(x)\right|^p dx\\
& = \sum_z \int_{Q_{\varepsilon}(z)} \left|\frac{1}{\varepsilon^n}\int_{Q_{\varepsilon}(z)}f(y)dy - f(x)\frac{\varepsilon^n}{\varepsilon^n}\right|^p dx \\
& = \sum_z \int_{Q_{\varepsilon}(z)} \frac{1}{\varepsilon^n}\left|\int_{Q_{\varepsilon}(z)}f(y)dy - f(x)\varepsilon^n\right|^p dx  \\
\\
& \text{(now since $f(x)$ is constant with respec to $y$}\\
&\text{ we have $\int_{Q_{\varepsilon}(z)}f(x)dy = f(x)\varepsilon^n$ and then)}\\
\\
&= \sum_z \int_{Q_{\varepsilon}(z)} \frac{1}{\varepsilon^n}\left|\int_{Q_{\varepsilon}(z)}(f(y) - f(x))dy\right|^p dx 
\end{split}$$
Now for \eqref{2} I believe it was a mistake from the author. You indeed can't include the absolute value operation in the integral and maintain equality in general, and there is no reason to believe in this case the integrand would be always positive. But since next step is finding another upper bound to this integral, it ends up not really messing with the proof
The idea from (2) to (3) is that the author wants to use the transform $(x,y) \to (y+h,y)$ for $h = x-y$. Then the integral would be taken over $y \in Q_{\varepsilon}(z)$ and in some domain $B$ where $h = x-y$ would range all over $Q_{\varepsilon}(z)$. That would yield:
$$ \sum_z\frac{1}{\varepsilon^n}\int_B \int_{Q_{\varepsilon}(z)} |f(y+h)-f(y)|^pdydh = \int_B \sum_z\frac{1}{\varepsilon^n}\int_{Q_{\varepsilon}(z)} |f(y+h)-f(y)|^pdydh \leq $$
$$ \leq \sup_{h\in B} \left[\sum_z\frac{1}{\varepsilon^n}\int_{Q_{\varepsilon}(z)}(|f(y+h)-f(y)|^p)dy\right]\,vol(B) $$
where $vol(B)$ denotes the volume (or the measure) of $B$. Now since for a fixed $y$, the set $\{y-h,\: h\in B\}$ must be exactly $Q_{\varepsilon}(z)$ we get that $vol(B) = vol(Q_{\varepsilon}(z)) = \varepsilon^n$. Then:
$$ \sup_{h\in B} \left[\sum_z\frac{1}{\varepsilon^n}\int_{Q_{\varepsilon}(z)}(|f(y+h)-f(y)|^p)dy\right]\,vol(B) = \sup_{h\in B} \left[\sum_z \int_{Q_{\varepsilon}(z)}(|f(y+h)-f(y)|^p)dy\right] \leq $$
$$ \leq  \sup_{h\in B} \left[\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(|f(y+h)-f(y)|^p)dy\right] = \sup_{h:|h|\leq \varepsilon} \left[\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(|f(y+h)-f(y)|^p)dy\right] $$
However I'm not all sure that these work. The point is that the author deals with some triviallity with the identity $B = \{h:|h| \leq \varepsilon\}$, which I'm not sure wether or not is true. In the case it is, then everything follows simply, but if it's not, I don't think the integrals can be taken in the order $\int_B \int_{Q_{\varepsilon}(z)}$ as I did above, as the $B$ set would depend on $y$. Anyway, I think the author took many hidden steps there and choose not to deal with the intricacies, as setting $\varepsilon \to 0$ would make the $B$ smaller and the $\sup$ opperations would indeed work in the desired way.

Thanks for the answer! Not sure where I got the idea that I can just pull a summand into an integral, so I would have never found that mistake. For (2) it worked out nicely with Jensen's inequality.

For (3) I am though stuck again: In $$\int_{Q_\epsilon(z)} \int_{Q_\epsilon(z)} |f(y) - f(x)|^p , dy , dx$$
I think we approximate one of $x,y$ by choosing the other as the supremum in some area including all of $Q_\epsilon(z)$. But no matter which of the two we choose way, the supremum is within the sum:
$$
\sum_z \sup_{h : |h| \leq \sqrt n \epsilon} \int_{Q_\epsilon(z)} |f(y + h) - f(y)|^p , dy
$$
And I'm not seeing that we can pull it out without changing the resulting value...

Or rather said we have $$\sum_z \sup_{h : |h| \leq \sqrt n \epsilon} \int_{Q_\epsilon(z)} |f(y + h) - f(y)|^p , dy
\ge  \sup_{h : |h| \leq \sqrt n \epsilon} \sum_z\int_{Q_\epsilon(z)} |f(y + h) - f(y)|^p , dy$$, but that's the wrong direction for the inequality

I eddited the answer to add some explanation for this, but I'm not sure if I was succesful

Thank you! With this, I could complete the proof. As for the set $B$, I still needed a factor $\sqrt n$ (assuming Euclidean norm, but since all norms are equivalent, that factor is in the end irrelevant). To make it precise: $$\begin{align}
&\quad\int_{Q}{\int_{Q}\left|f\left(y\right)-f\left(x\right)\right|^pdy}dx
\&=
\int_{Q}{\int_{{h\in\mathbb{R}^n|x+h\in Q}}\left|f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x\right)\right|^pdh}dx
\&\le
\int_{Q}{\int_{{h\in\mathbb{R}^n||h|≤nϵ}}\left|f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x\right)\right|^pdh}dx
\end{align}
$$ and now we can pull it all the way out
